# T-SQL - How can I copy a database and keep security settings intact?

Tags: t-sql

I have a SQL 2005 Express database with security configured for Windows authentication on my development machine. Occasionally I need to copy it to a SQL 2008 R2 test server that uses SQL authentication. I've tried detaching and attaching the development copy on the test server, as well as restoring a development backup on the test server, but in both cases the SQL account's role membership and permissions that I had configured previously are lost and I have to reconfigure them.

Is there a way to copy the database to the test server and keep the existing SQL user security configuration intact after restore/attach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:
The SSMS GUI has a quick'n'dirty way to copy users: , Tasks, Generate scripts ...., select "users".

Here's another alternative:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;246133

Comment: Thanks but these methods appear to just copy logins. The role membership and permissions don't remain intact when I run the generated script.

Comment: This worked. The script generated by running the proc in that article allowed me to create a user with the same SID on the development machine. What I missed is that I had to set up the role membership and permissions _before_ I backed up and copied the database to the test server. Thanks!

Comment: My regular user didn't have permissions to script all database objects from my workstation - I needed to log in on the server itself in order to get the full script to generate successfully.

Answer (score 4):

You might be experiencing a problem known as "Orphaned users", [which is discussed in this Mircosoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

Basically, the user exists in the database, and the login exist on the server, but the SPIDs don't match, so the user isn't associated with the login when the database is restored or attached to the server.

As discussed in the article, the `sp_change_users_login` stored procedure can be used to resolve individual logins, and the following script will attempt to auto-fix all users in the database:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('tempdb..#t_users'))
    drop table #t_users

CREATE TABLE #t_users ( [name] SYSNAME)

INSERT #t_users ( [name] )
SELECT [name] 
FROM sysusers 
WHERE 
    islogin = 1 
    AND name NOT IN ('dbo', 'public', 'guest', 'sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')  
order by name

DECLARE @lc_name SYSNAME

SET @lc_name = (SELECT MIN([name]) FROM #t_users)
WHILE @lc_name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master..syslogins WHERE [name] = @lc_name)
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_change_users_login 'AUTO_FIX', @lc_name
        PRINT 'fixing ' + @lc_name
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT '*** not fixing ' + @lc_name

    SET @lc_name = (SELECT MIN([name]) FROM #t_users WHERE [name] > @lc_name )
END
```

Comment: Apparently the SQL user account on the test server isn't considered orphaned; `sp_change_users_login @Action='Report'` shows no results.

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson - good call.  "sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix'"/orphaned users is a common problem I've run into often - it's definitely something to remember.